# Google Maps Transit - Search on my own bus lines

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to "Google Maps Transit" service/API to search only on my bus lines table?
I will provide itinerary data for each bus line using "Google Maps Directions" service.

Thanks,
Marcos